# how to set up server's localhost to IP?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've got my system running and I want to connect it to the Server!

So my problem is this line of code

```
    mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; userid=root; password=; database=dbfsesmis"
```

As you can see my server is localhost or 127.0.0.1, but I want is that main server's ip address and localhost(). Please Help me!

I'm using mysql database using XAMPP and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You probably just want to type ipconfig into the console of windows on the server to get your ipv4 address `Windows + R ` => `cmd` => `Enter` => `ipconfig` => `Enter`Otherwise, if you want to change the localhost - Target on the server, then go to the hosts file: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: example I've got 3 client pc's and 1 server. what will I put on the server in the connecton strng ? the IP of the server? I've tried it but it prompt an error